# XStream deserialization of generic class returns java.lang.Object

Tags: java, xml, generics, xstream

I'm struggling to convert some XML into objects of generic classes. My code works well with non-generic classes, but doesn't with generic ones.

Let's look at this example, it makes it easier to explain. I use both generic and non-generic classes to compare their behaviour.

**Xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Box>
    <doubleFieldA>
        <myGenericField>20.3</myGenericField>
    </doubleFieldA>
    <doubleFieldB>
        <myNonGenericField>20.3</myNonGenericField>
    </doubleFieldB>
</Box>
```

**Xsd schema:**

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Box">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="doubleFieldA">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:double" name="myGenericField"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="doubleFieldB">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:double" name="myNonGenericField"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

**GenericClass.java:**

```
public class GenericClass<T> {
    public T myGenericField;
}
```

**NonGenericClass.java:**

```
public class NonGenericClass {
    public double myNonGenericField;
}
```

**Box.java:**

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Box {
    public GenericClass<Double> doubleFieldA;
    public NonGenericClass doubleFieldB;

    private void deserialize() {
        Box b;
        String s;
        XStream xs = new XStream();
        try{
            s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/my_xml.xml")));
            b = (Box)xs.fromXML(s);
            doubleFieldA = b.doubleFieldA;
            doubleFieldB = b.doubleFieldB;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Box() {
        deserialize();
    }
}
```

**Main.java:**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box box = new Box();
        System.out.println("myGenericField = " + box.doubleFieldA.myGenericField);
        System.out.println("myNonGenericField = " + box.doubleFieldB.myNonGenericField);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> myGenericField = java.lang.Object@2d928643
>
> myNonGenericField = 20.3

**Expected output (what I want!):**

> myGenericField = 20.3
>
> myNonGenericField = 20.3

I have a Box class with two attributes: one is a generic class, the other just a normal class.
Both have an attribute, whose type is double in this particular example.
I try to initialize them with the values stored in the XML file (20.3 for both), using XStream.
Eventually, when I print these attributes, I get the correct value for the non-generic class. The generic class attribute, on the contrary, results in a java.lang.Object.
**How should I modify my code to obtain the expected behaviour?**

I suspect the issue may be in the way XStream handles generic types, but I'm not sure. 
I don't have much experience with XStream and XML technologies in general, so I'd really appreciate an answer with working code/examples rather than "you need to implement XYZ, find out how in this messy tutorial!".

Thank you very much!

Note: the only purpose of this code is to show my issue. I encountered this problem in a way larger project, so this is just a small example to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **good** way to do it with XStream, it just doesn't have any idea that generics even exist. You can add custom converter:

```
public static class BoxConverter implements Converter {

    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
            return clazz.equals(Box.class);
    }

    public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer,
                    MarshallingContext context) {
            throw new RuntimeException("to do");
    }

    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader,
                    UnmarshallingContext context) {
            Box box = new Box();
             while (reader.hasMoreChildren()) {
                    reader.moveDown();
                    if ("doubleFieldA".equals(reader.getNodeName())) {
                            reader.moveDown();
                            Double val = Double.valueOf(reader.getValue());
                            reader.moveUp();
                            GenericClass<Double> genericObject = new GenericClass<>();
                            genericObject.myGenericField = val;
                            box.doubleFieldA = genericObject;
                    } else if ("doubleFieldB".equals(reader.getNodeName())) {
                            box.doubleFieldB =(NonGenericClass)context.convertAnother(box, NonGenericClass.class);
                    }
                    reader.moveUp();
            }
            return box;
    }
}
```

And the register it:

```
XStream xs = new XStream();
xs.registerConverter(new BoxConverter());
Box b = (Box) xs.fromXML(input);
```

But that requires to write a separate converter for each class that has GenericClass as a field/member. Notice that when you marshal such object with XStream it generates:

```
<Box>
  <doubleFieldA>
    <myGenericField class="double">20.3</myGenericField>
  </doubleFieldA>
  <doubleFieldB>
    <myNonGenericField>20.3</myNonGenericField>
  </doubleFieldB>
</Box>
```

and that additional `class="double"` is something that XStream is unable to infer on its own.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem here is [TypeErasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), especially

> Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

So

```
public T myGenericField;
```

becomes

```
public Object myGenericField;
```

at runtime/in the bytecode.

So there's no way for XStream to determine myGenericField should be a double... and so it get's deserialized into an `Object` instance.

`java.lang.Object@2d928643` is just the output of `myGenericField.toString()`

So, only way I see is to create a [custom converter](http://x-stream.github.io/converters.html).

Comment: Actually no, Type Erasure is not a problem here, all required information is available at runtime. Try printing out: `Box.class.getField("doubleFieldA").getGenericType()`, `GenericClass.class.getTypeParameters()` and `GenericClass.class.getField("myGenericField").getGenericType()`
you will get:
`GenericClass<java.lang.Double>`, `[T]` and `T`

Comment: Hmm ok, then Type Erasure isn't an *unsolvable* Problem here, but Type Erausre paired with the fact that XStream doesn't honor the generic information availiable seems to be...